# date format issue with google data studio (postgres)

Tags: sql, database, looker-studio

I'm using Postgres connector from a cloud based server to Google Data Studio, to pull in all my Zoho CRM data so that I can build some dashboards in Google Data Studio.

Problem is, for some odd reason it's refusing to accept some of my date fields, while others it does. Even the exact same field, in one of my Zoho CRM tables it works, another location (sep zoho account) it won't.

I get this error:

Data Set Configuration Error
Data Studio cannot connect to your data set.

Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.

Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
Error ID: e1c58806

Nothing I've done seems to help.

I'm using Panopoly.io as the server.

Zoho CRM Enterprise

And obviously Google Data Studio.

Data Set Configuration Error
Data Studio cannot connect to your data set.

Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.

Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
Error ID: e1c58806

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue with two timestamp columns I was pulling from a PostgreSQL view: `start` and `end`. Changing the type of the columns in Data Studio did not fix it, and in some cases it would even complain about a syntax error with the `end` column as it was interpolating the column's name without properly escaping it or something of the sort.

What finally fixed it was renaming the columns to `start_date` and `end_date`. After that, even though the configuration of the dataset was the same, everything started working.